# Angular Load Data on Scroll [For Loop]

Tags: angular

I am showing the data related to the search term. This data shows all the results at once.

What I want to do is show 6 data once and load the remaining on a scroll.

```
<li *ngFor="let category of categories">
  {{ category.name }}
</li>
```

How can I show data on scroll?

Comment: You could use ngx-infinite-scroll : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll.

Comment: @ibenjelloun I hate extra-packages :)

Comment: It is open source, you can read the code for inspiration then create your own implementation without adding the lib : https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll

Comment: @Sanjay don't try to reinvent wheel again, you could end putting extra effort :p

Comment: @PankajParkar That's how you learn stuff. Effort is a part of learning :)

Comment: I believe in the same. But productivity matters alot. Sometime using well known third party package, and going though there their code taught me a lot. May I know the reason why you chosen Angular?

Comment: @PankajParkar “Productivity is being able to do things that you were never able to do before.” ~ Franz Kafka! I believe in that. Anyway, it's not that I don't use the third-party packages. Instead, I always try to minimize the usage of these packages and code from scratch. This method trains my coding skill. As a matter of fact, there comes a time when you won't be able to do all by yourself. And, I met with Angular at that particular time. I hope I have answered your question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could listen to the `window:scroll` events and load data when the scroll reaches the bottom of the page :

```
  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onScroll(): void {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
      // Load Your Data Here
    }
  }
```

[Here is a running stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scroll-n-roll)

Comment: The only issue with it is when resizing the page until no scroll bar on the page, the page cannot load the rest of the data.

Comment: adding window.scrollY * 1.1 effectively pre-loads pages and gives a slightly nicer experience

Comment: Thank you Mathias for your suggestion, how did you test that ? Can you make a fork with your change and explain how I could notice the difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To auto load data using scroll, we can get the element or div scrollHeight and match with window scroll Y axis height and execute. Here is the code below. Hope it helps

**results.component.ts**

```
 page: number = 1;

 @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  scrollHandler(event: any) {
    var insightsResults = document.getElementsByClassName(
      'insights-results'
    )[0];
    var childInsights = insightsResults?.scrollHeight;
    var windowScroll = window.scrollY;
    if (Math.floor(windowScroll) >= Math.floor(childInsights)) {
        this.loadMore();
    }
  }
  
  
   loadMore(): void {
    this.page++;
  }
```

**results.component.html**

```
<ul
      *ngIf="insights && insights.length"
      class="insights-results__card-list"
      (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)">
      <li
        class="insights-results__card"
        *ngFor="let card of insights | slice: 0:pageSize * page">
        <app-insights-card
          [locale]="locale"
          [data]="card"
          variant="vertical"
        ></app-insights-card>
      </li>
    </ul>

 <div
      *ngIf="insights && insights.length > pageSize * page"
      class="insights-results__button-wrapper">
      <button
        class="insights-results__button"
        (click)="loadMore()"
        [disabled]="pageLoading">
        <span *ngIf="!pageLoading">{{ data.seeMoreResultsCtaText }}</span>
        <span *ngIf="pageLoading">{{ data.loadingText }}</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```