# How to pre-load components (without route) in Angular?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I know about pre loading strategies, but they only work based on routes. I have a couple of lazy loaded components that I would like to pre-load (but not to have inside the AppModule), using a custom preload strategy.

Is it possible or am I forced to assign these components a route (that should be never used, maybe made unreachable by a guard)?

Comment: I believe you are required to call a function manually to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70275229/how-to-lazy-load-angular-components-of-the-home-page