# *ngIf condition is not fired/doesn't update template in ngOnChanges

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-template, ionic3

I have a child a component that does not fire the condition for `*ngIf`

child component:

```
 export class child {
    @Input() user;
    @Input() list;

    listLength: number;
    showBtn: boolean = false;

 constructor(){}

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){

     this.userId = this.user.id;
     this.userList = this.list;
     this.listLength = this.userList.length;   // this updates everytime when changes happen on another component thats pushed from this component.

     if (this.listLength > 3){    // this doesn't fire until I refresh the page
        this.showBtn = true;
     }
```

Comment: are you able to log the `listLength` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with `ngDoCheck()` lifeCycle hook.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
 this.userId = this.user.id;
 this.userList = this.list;
}

ngDoCheck(){
 if (this.list.length > 3){
        this.showBtn = true; 
    } else {
        this.showBtn = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably also get an error output in the browsers console.
Invoke change detection explicitly if you update the model in `ngOnChanges()`

```
  constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){

     this.userId = this.user.id;
     this.userList = this.list;
     this.listLength = this.userList.length;   // this updates everytime when changes happen on another component thats pushed from this component.

     if (this.listLength > 3){    // this doesn't fire until I refresh the page
        this.showBtn = true;
     }
     this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess then you'll need to provide more information. Ideally a Plunker that allows to reproduce the problem. Plunker provides an Angular template under the `New` button.

Answer (score 1):

An Array has a static pointer. When you add or remove elements from the Array in Angular2, the array pointer stays the same and thus the view doesnt get updated until you refresh your browser. This is due to the angular2 change detection system. Atleast this is my guess.

Someone wrote a beautiful answer about Angular2 change detection in this article, maybe it will help you.

[angular 2 change detection and ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795634/angular-2-change-detection-and-changedetectionstrategy-onpush)

Comment: thanx bro, very useful.